# Transferring data from android device to a custom device

Tags: android, serial-port, communication

I'm quite new in android (I'm able to develop simple android apps by Android Studio). I've build a board (a custom device) which is wired connected to and can communicate through a wifi module by a simple UART 232 COM port.

The wifi module can create an Access Point (Like a wi-fi local area network) by which is possible to connect with any android device.

Now I saw that if I use an android APP like teraterm I can transfer data once I'm connected to the device trought wifi, so can anyone tell me where to find information on how to built a custom application that, connecting to the WLAN, is able to exchange data to my custom device like a COM port does?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add any link to the descirption of use of "teraterm" you write about?

Comment: Any Telnet App over a WiFi is fine
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luk4sproductions.telnetclient
Once the module boots up in Access Point mode, any client device can associate with the network the module is broadcasting. Once associated, the module’s DHCP server assigns an IP address to the client device. Then, with a TelNet application is possible to exchange data and the wifi module works as a simple "connection cable" between my custom device and the user App